# With SQL how to select rows that the joined table matches 2 values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

If we have a table, orders:

| Order ID | Order Table |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 50 |

And we have a table, OrderProducts:

| OrderID | Product ID | ProductName | ProductType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ProductOne | Small |
| 1 | 2 | ProductTwo | Big |
| 1 | 3 | ProductThree | Small |
| 2 | 4 | ProductFour | Big |
| 2 | 5 | ProductFive | Big |

How do I use SQL to return only the Orders that contain products of 2 specific types.  In the scenario above I want to return only products with ProductType = 'Small' and 'Big' but ignore orders like "2" which only have products of two 'Big' on.

Results:

| Order ID |
| --- |
| 1 |

I have tried creating a view to help, inner joins with multiple clauses but I am struggling.  I am using MySQL for this and think my logic is simply "out".

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation is one method:

```
select order_id
from orderproducts op
where ProductType in ('Small', 'Big')
group by order_id
having count(distinct ProductType) = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried a few variants of this myself but just had the logic wrong. I appreciate the help. Have a good weekend.